# How to edit HTML of a single page in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, background

(General Kenobi).

Alright, enough fun lets get to the point. I have a question about Wordpress for you guys and I hope you can help me with it. My theme supports an image as an "ad" which you can place below header (menu) and above content on the site. It is not a background, you can set BG of a page and then in theme options add image to be shown.

[image: See this picture please.]

The problem is, this picture is now on every page, article, everywhere on site. I can live with that but I would like to know if its possible to somehow change HTML or something of a single WordPress page and replace the logo with the different image? I clearly can't do that in editor as it supports only one image for everything so that's why I'm asking to try out code change. I tried to get to the HTML but in WP Editor it shows only a few lines of PHP code.

As I'm typing this I'm realizing some huge problems it might have but I'll post this anyway, maybe some of you will have a great tip :) Thanks for helping me out in any way!

Michal

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you want to some html with be render only on homepage you can wrap the code with `if ( is_home() ) {`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/#user-contributed-notes